# Flexbox list alignment leaving space between elements on 3 element row

Tags: html, css, list, flexbox, alignment

I am having an issues with flexbox list alignment.  I have a list of elements displayed over a row of 3. But on a row with 2 elements there is a space in the middle.

I aim aiming for a row with only 2 elements to look like x x o. However my code leave the elements like this x o x.  I also note that the elements arent entirely centered to its div.

See below:

[Flexbox alignment issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyiNd.png)

I have my ul set to:

```
 display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width:100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
```

and the li with:

```
{
    color:black;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
```

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content . it is working as expected from your code.

Comment: Remove `justify-content: space-between;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space in the middle is caused by space-between. For that particular row just leave it to follow the normal row without any style. And it will start from the left to the right. If you want to create stuff that follows in that particular order, You can use a grid instead which is easier to do.

```
ul {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

This will make it follow in a nice order, just the way you want it.

Or if you still want to use flexbox, for that particular row

```
ul{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

li{
width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately when i do this i get strange results.  For instance i would have 9 elements in one row and no other rows.  I will take a look at grid but i would like to understand the flexbox.

Comment: To use flex box, you would have to have three ul's and three li in each. So i suggest grid.